# How to load a TEMPORARY (GTT) table in Oracle with SQL*Loader to supercharge transient data staging

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

This is a Q&A sharing of something I learned how to do that has been reported for years to not be possible. **How to get SQL*Loader to load** ***temporary*** **tables** (global temporary tables, or GTTs).

Systems which involve huge quantities of volatile data being pumped into raw staging tables in a database repository where they are needed only for a minute or two until that data is processed (e.g. by PL/SQL) into some final form are paying a stiff penalty of writing all that staging data to permanent tables, with all the concurrency mechanisms, redo, undo (and, if conventional, stress on the buffer cache and elevated DBWR and LGWR activity) and then having to pay all this penalty over again with deletes to remove the no-longer-needed staging data, or thrashing the dictionary and taking out all manner of concurrency mechanisms dynamically creating and dropping tables.

It makes much more sense to load the staging data to temporary (GTT) tables, which is far more efficient for transient data for all the above reasons and doesn't require cleanup afterwards. But no website or blog or stackoverflow post has never suggested that this is possible. First, SQLLoader will complain about loading a GTT directly. Secondly, even if it could, the data would be visible only to the SQLLoader session itself, and disappear upon its completion. When would you do the PL/SQL processing of that data? It won't be there anymore. So it has been chalked up as not doable.

Wrong.

I've been doing it for hundreds of thousands of times per day for years now with amazing results. See how below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

1. Create your GTT(s). Be sure to use the ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS option.
2. Create a view for each GTT, defined as select * from the GTT.
3. Direct SQL*Loader to load into the *view*. This gets past the first issue - SQL*Loader will no longer complain about loading a GTT, but it will successfully do so through the view.

Now for the magic:

4. Create a dummy table with a single column
5. Create another dummy table. It's up to you whether you have columns that are meaningful or not.
6. (A bit hacky) Whatever your BATCHSIZE parameter (rows per commit) is set to in SQL*Loader, generate that many rows as dummy data and add that to your data file. In shell, something like:

   ```
    echo "DUMMY" | awk '{for(i=0;i<=2000;i++) print}' >> data.dat
   ```

   Use your control file to direct this to the dummy table created in step #4. What you load doesn't matter. This is necessary because you will be operating in an autonomous transaction, so you won't be able to see any loaded rows not yet committed, even though you will be operating within the same session (see below). This ensures that SQLLoader will get to a commit point after your last real data row before it gets to your trigger row.
7. Add one last dummy line that the control file will direct to the other dummy table created in step #5 above. It doesn't have to have any meaningful information, but in my application I do use it to specify which PL/SQL package to call since I have multiple versions. Here's mine:

   ```
   echo "PACKAGECALL pkg_snapshot_80" >> data.dat
   ```
8. Create an AFTER INSERT ON [dummy table] FOR EACH ROW trigger on the packagecall dummy table that the PACKAGECALL record will be inserted into. This trigger must use the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION because your PL/SQL processing will be committing and you can't do that within a trigger execution without starting an autonomous transaction. That's also why we needed those dummy rows to force a commit after our last real data row and before the trigger fires so we can see all the rows. The trigger may now execute the PL/SQL routine that will process your data into its final form.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_PACKAGECALL
   AFTER INSERT
   ON GTT$PACKAGECALL
   REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
   FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE
     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   BEGIN
     /* kick off processing to final model tables */
     pkg_snapshot_80.p_gtt_staging_wrapper;
   END;
   ```

SQLLoader will load your GTT(s) without any knowledge that they are special, then as a result of loading the 2000 dummy rows (in my example) will commit, then will load the last row which will cause the trigger to be executed in the SQLLoader's own session. Because it is in it's own session, it can see the data it loaded in the GTTs... your PL/SQL routines can happily work on that GTT data. When you are done, you simply exit, which will end SQL*Loader and the staging data in the GTTs (in temp segments) is instantly dropped without any penalty.

SQL*Loader of course wasn't designed to be used this way, so doesn't have a way of passing back any status code or message from your routine.  If you need that, you can place the processing return code and any messages in a messaging table and your client can query that table after SQL Loader is done to retrieve that status. A bit awkward, but it works fine and is totally worth the benefit this approach provides.

This has revolutionized my database's health and made it able to smoothly handle much more staging load than it was able to do with permanent tables. Far less waits, less I/O, faster, and a happier programmer. Hopefully this can help someone else out there.